# R - split string with 2 delimiters, remove duplicate and put the frame back?

Tags: r, duplicates, delimiter

I have the following dataframe (df1):

```
someName    someMOD someValue   someID  someSymbol
FGR8    A(P);A(Z);M(O),A(Z),P(L)    4234    1   X
MZ66    C(P),M(O);M(O),A(Z),P(L)    434 23  Y
O161    A(P);A(Z);M(O),A(Z),P(L)    23  32  Z
O001    A(P),A(Z);M(O),A(P);M(O)    5   5   W
O0019   Z(P);A(Z),M(O),A(Z),Z(P)    34345   3   K
```

I would like to split the someMOD column by ',' and then ';'    ...then remove the duplicated values and put the string back together with a comma.
I think first we will use unlist with strsplit and then again with the semi-colon separator, then remove duplicates but how to put it back with commas?

```
semicolony <-  unlist(strsplit(df1$someMOD,','))
commay <- unlist(strsplit(semicolony$someMOD,';'))
commay <- commay[!duplicated(commay[,1]),]
commay = paste(commay, collapse=',')
```

Desired output

```
someName    someMOD someValue   someID  someSymbol
FGR8    A(P),A(Z),M(O),P(L) 4234    1   X
MZ66    C(P),M(O),A(Z),P(L) 434 23  Y
O161    A(P),A(Z),M(O),P(L) 23  32  Z
O001    A(P),A(Z),M(O)  5   5   W
O0019   Z(P),A(Z),M(O)  34345   3   K
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```
SplitFunction <- function(x) {
  b <- unlist(strsplit(x, '[;,]'))
  c <- b[!duplicated(b)]
  return(paste(c, collapse=","))
}

SplitFunctionV <- Vectorize(SplitFunction)
df$someMOD <- SplitFunctionV(df$someMOD)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
x <- df1$someMOD
x2 <- strsplit(x, ",")
x3 <- lapply(x2,FUN=function(x) unlist(strsplit(x,";")))
x4 <- lapply(x3, unique)
x5 <- unlist(lapply(x4,paste,collapse=","))
```

I should mention this could be combined into fewer steps to avoid repeating the `lapply`'s, but wanted to follow the steps in the original question (the main problem in which was the initial use of `unlist`).